# Processing data returned from Invoke-Command as it's received?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I have a PowerShell script that I want to run on 5,000+ endpoints.  The script enumerates a bunch of information about each host which I then want to be able to ingest into another program for analysis.

The problem I'm having is that Invoke-Command does not allow me to process the data returned from each machine as it's received.  This is an issue because with 5,000+ endpoints I run into memory constraints on the machine I'm running Invoke-Command from.

Ideally I'd like to be able to execute a script block each time I receive a response from a machine.  Something similar to this, for example:

```
$ProcessOutput = {
    # $_ = Data returned from one machine    
    $_ | Out-File ($_.PSComputerName)
}

Invoke-Command -FilePath $ScriptPath -ComputerName $Computers -ProcessingScriptBlock $ProcessOutput
```

Is this already possible and I am overlooking something?  Or is the best solution to just split my computer list into chunks and scan each chunk one by one (resulting in longer run times)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jobs, `foreach -parallel` (in a workflow) or runspaces (faster, but more complicated than jobs) to run parallel workloads. Here's an example using jobs which is the easiest to read.

```
$ProcessOutput = {
    # $_ = Data returned from one machine    
    $_ | Out-File "$($_.PSComputerName).txt"
}

$Computers = "localhost", "frode-pc"

#Start job
$mainjob = Invoke-Command -FilePath $ScriptPath -ComputerName $Computers -AsJob

#Process results as they complete
while ($mainjob.State -eq "Running") {
    $mainjob.ChildJobs | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Completed' } | Receive-Job | ForEach-Object $ProcessOutput
}

#Process last job(s)
$mainjob.ChildJobs | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Completed' } | Receive-Job | ForEach-Object $ProcessOutput
```

If performance is critical, use runspaces. Check out [`Invoke-Parallel`](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) for an easy-to-use implementation of runspaces

Comment: [Boe Prox created a great module called PoshRSJob](https://learn-powershell.net/2015/03/31/introducing-poshrsjob-as-an-alternative-to-powershell-jobs/) that lets you use runspaces in a manner similar to PSJobs, but even better.

Comment: Will check it out. Added `Invoke-Parallel` in my answer as a runspace-solution. I usually do it the manual way with my own homemade script-templates for runspaces (I have a couple using different timeout-systems) :-)